# What topics for a training class?

Tags: asp.net, .net

We have a team of developers in India.  I will be visiting them for a week at the end of the month.  Part of my job while I'm there is to provide them with some training.  I've been code reviewing them for almost 2 years so I have a few specific things that I'd like to coach them on.  My question to the SO community is this:

What general topics would be useful to a team of Jr-Mid lvl Asp.Net developers?

Comment: What's your definition of a Jr-Mid lvl Asp.Net developer? As I'm sure my definition will be different.

Comment: Jr - Mid lvl asp.net developers (in my mind) can fix bugs or implement new features when given a pattern to follow.  They are also responsible for adding their own methods to a DAL which might include writing their own simple TSQL queries more often than not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An in depth look at the page Life Cycle.  Almost everyone will learn something new once you get deep into the details of when each event is thrown, and what exactly is set up and available when handling each event.

If you are using Web.Extensions you can show how it affects the events.  Introduce Page.IsAsync, etc.

Comment: This is so true.  The page life cycle is so important yet it feels like most developers have virtually no concept of it other than the page load, and even that one they'll get wrong and not even know it!

Answer (score 2):

Security.

General security concepts, application security techniques, secure coding guidelines, security best practices and principles, etc.
Depending on available time (and their level), you should focus on data validation, data validation, data validation, and then on output sanitization (encoding), authentication mechanisms, data access, error handling, etc.

Then again, since this topic(s) is pretty complicated, you might prefer outsourcing it to security experts.

Answer (score 0):

How about some non technical stuff....

To start with...

1. Setting clear expectations in terms of this is what is acceptable, this is not.
2. We expect response in say an hour even if it is a one liner saying "we are looking into the issue and would get back to you as soon as possible."
3. Let them know its fine to say "I don't know" only if followed by "How can I learn it?"
4. You can tell them about the problem you face, the things that frustrate you and the kind of help you need from these guys..

Usually offshore teams face a lot of anxiety in terms of the expectations of the onshore team, making them comfortable would make things much smoother...

This is what I would expect from a Senior Onshore Developer to tell me...so that we can work better as a team...

Comment: Can anybody think of anything else?